# Get text from an editetext and request a json for a listview

Tags: android

I want to have a search bar that searches a json file and parses it into an listview, i already have finished parsing a link but i need the text that is typed into the edit text. This is the code i got so far, it puts the text that has been typed in the edittext to an textview :

```
package it.experium.ccapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;


public class MainActivity2Activity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText edit;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

        //setup ui
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView18);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_show);

        //event handeling using onclick interface
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //getting the text from edittext
                String name = edit.getText().toString();
                //appending the text to the textview
                text.append(name);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1):

So you simply want to replace the text in TextView with the text you have in EditText on button pressed?

try:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //getting the text from edittext
            String name = edit.getText().toString();
            //appending the text to the textview
            text.setText(name);
        }
```

***EDIT***

Create an AsyncTask with your parameters

```
            AsyncTask asyncTask= new AsyncTask();

            //create an object with your parameters
            TaskParam param = new TaskParam("param1",name,"param2", 0);
            asyncTask.execute(param);
```

Comment: if you read my problem right i need to get the text to request a json file ;)

Comment: Haven't you implemented an AsyncTask? Just pass the text to the AsyncTask and send it to the Server – see EDIT